# Get text after after html tag using Jsoup and display the results

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to get text from the HTML document

```
<p>
   <b>1</b>First Text
   <b>2</b><br>Second Text
   <b>3</b>Third Text
   .
   .
   .
   .
</p>
```

line no 3 is where things gets stuck

Tried with below code, but there occurs an error.

```
Elements elements = doc.body().select("p").select("b");
    for(int i=0; i<elements.size(); i++)
{
        Element val = elements.get(i);

    if ((val.nextSibling().toString().trim()).equals(""))
        System.out.println(val.nextSibling().toString().select("br").first().text()+"\n");
    else
        System.out.println(val.nextSibling().toString()+"\n");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear but it seems (from the title) that you only want the text outside the `<b>`'s after the `<br>`. For this you can use the `ownText()`:

```
Elements elements = doc.select("p");
for(Element p: elements) {
    System.out.println(p.ownText()); // Prints text that is in <p> but not in <b>
}
```

Comment: Hi Pphoenix, Thanks for your answer. Sorry for an unclear question. I wish to store each element within <b></b> tag and the text near to, in an 2d array. but the problem with my code snippet was when it encounters <br> unclosed tag. error occured. but I found a solution last day. caught the exception and used .nextSibling().nextSibling() and my work is done.